# What's the correct type hint for a type hint?

Tags: python, type-annotation

I have a use case for accepting type hints as arguments to a function. But what is the right type hint to to accept a type hint?

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound='TypeHintType')

def register_handler(type_hint: T, handler: Handler[T]) -> None:
    ...
```

Is there a "TypeHintType" that I can use to annotate that a type hint is expected as an argument?

Comment: I'm inspecting type hints at runtime to serialize dataclasses to JSON. A type hint (e.g. `Union`, `Optional`, `List`, etc.) can be associated with a `Converter` class, which will then be looked up to perform the serialization (package already is on PyPI: [databind](https://pypi.org/project/databind.core/)). I would like to make it pass Mypy checks

Comment: Dispatching on actual types is not sufficient if you need to be able to understand concepts like `Optional` and `Union` for the serialization. You can retrieve the fully evaluated type hints at runtime with `typing.get_type_hints()` (or the raw annotations with `obj.__annotations__`).

Comment: Oh, you're altering `__annotations__`? I've never needed to do that, but `type` should suffice. `type(Optional)` and `type(Union)` are both `typing._SpecialForm`, which is just a class. If you check `__annotations__`, the values of it are just `type`s.

Comment: Not actually altering it, more like using it to derive how to serialize a `dataclass`. You're right, those are `typing._SpecialForm` instances, so theoretically I should be able to write something like `type_hint: typing._SpecialForm`, but that's not a member of the `typing` public API and will yield another Mypy error. (If you `# type: ignore` that error Mypy treats the type hint as `Any` instead of `typing._SpecialForm`).